# Nand gate wiring simulator in clojure

Tags: clojure

Maybe this is a little large for a simple code review, but I think it included a lot of different needs and how I tried to meet them. Pick a section or function and let me know where I might improve.
The code is for a nand gate simulator and takes an input file with wiring pairs. Like variable to gate or gate to other gate. Example input at end.

```
;;Namespace
(ns wiring.core (:gen-class) (:use clojure.set))
;;Reading in file in groups of 2 char sequences at a time to get wiring pairs.
(defn get-wiring-groups
  [filename]
  (partition 2 (re-seq #"[a-zA-Z0-9]+" (slurp filename))))
;;Checks each of the sequences for whether or not the first character is a
;;number
;;or letter sequence. Sets letters as variables. Because it only checks first
;;Outputs may be letters aswell. Restricting only middle inputs to be numbers.
(defn get-variable-set
  [wiring-groups]
  (reduce (fn [build-set [variable? number]]
            (if (not (number? (read-string variable?)))
              (conj build-set variable?)
              build-set))
    #{}
    wiring-groups))
;;For putting together wires under same output
(defn merge-wires
  [new-wire wire-list]
  (merge-with (fn [x y] (list x y)) new-wire wire-list))
;;Creates the wiring map using merge-wires on wiring-groups
(defn get-wiring-map-no-defaults
  [wiring-groups]
  (reduce (fn [build-map [from to]] (merge-wires build-map {to from}))
    {}
    wiring-groups))
;;Turns single input gates to true and single input
(defn add-defaults
  [wiring-map]
  (reduce-kv (fn [m k v]
               (if (list? v) (conj m [k v]) (conj m [k (list v true)])))
             {}
             wiring-map))
;;Gets real wiring map
(defn get-wiring-map
  [wiring-groups]
  (-> wiring-groups
      (get-wiring-map-no-defaults)
      (add-defaults)))

;;Checks wiring list to find all inputs, used later for finding which are
;;outputs.
(defn get-input-set
  [wiring-groups]
  (reduce #(conj %1 (first %2)) #{} wiring-groups))
;;Doubles a list by adding a copy to end
(defn double-list [l] (flatten (repeat 2 l)))
;;Doubles a list by repeating each element twice
(defn double-elements [l] (reverse (reduce #(conj %1 %2 %2) '() l)))
;;Creates a list of n possible inputs true or false.
(defn gen-possibilities
  [letter-count]
  (loop [n letter-count
         [start :as all] (list (list true false))]
    (if (> n 1)
      (recur (- n 1) (conj (map double-elements all) (double-list start)))
      all)))
;;Takes the first from each of the possibilities lists and pairs them with
;;their
;;variable in a map
(defn get-current-possibilities [letters all] (zipmap letters (map first all)))
;;Checks if value is boolean
(defn boolean? [v] (or (true? v) (false? v)))
;;Simple nand gate that takes two boolean inputs
(defn nand [in1 in2] (not (and in1 in2)))
;;Checks to see if wire value is known. If so it returns the known value
;;otherwise it returns the wire.
(defn check-known
  [known wire]
  (if (contains? known wire) (get known wire) wire))
;;Interprets a single wire by using nand gate or looking up value
(defn interpret-single
  [[build-new-unknown known] k [wire1 wire2]]
  (if (and (boolean? wire1) (boolean? wire2))
    [build-new-unknown (conj known [k (nand wire1 wire2)])]
    [(conj build-new-unknown
           [k [(check-known known wire1) (check-known known wire2)]]) known]))
;;Interprets one step (either getting nand value or looking up) each wire
(defn interpret
  [unknown known]
  (reduce-kv #(interpret-single %1 %2 %3) [{} known] unknown))
;;Steps till all wire outputs are known
(defn step-all
  [unk kno]
  (loop [[unknown known] [unk kno]]
    (if (not (empty? unknown)) (recur (interpret unknown known)) known)))
;;Calls step all on each possible sequence of inputs
(defn do-all-possibilities
  [wiring letters possibilities-lists]
  (loop [all possibilities-lists
         outputs []]
    (if (not (empty? (first all)))
      (recur (map rest all)
             (conj outputs
                   (step-all wiring (get-current-possibilities letters all))))
      outputs)))
;;Takes in a set and will take those elements from the list of maps
(defn take-results-from
  [s results-list]
  (for [results results-list]
    (filter (fn [[wire output]] (contains? s wire)) results)))
;;Prints the input and output section titles
(defn print-titles
  [inputs]
  (printf (str "%-" (* 10 inputs) "s") "INPUTS")
  (print "OUTPUTS"))
;;Prints the input and output names
(defn print-headers
  [[variables]]
  (doseq [[variable value] variables] (printf "%-10s" variable)))
;;Prints all output and input values
(defn print-vals
  [variables]
  (doseq [[variable value] variables] (printf "%-10s" value)))
;;Driver
(defn -main
  [input-file]
  (let [wiring-groups (get-wiring-groups input-file)
        wiring-map (get-wiring-map wiring-groups)
        variable-set (get-variable-set wiring-groups)
        output-set (difference (set (keys wiring-map))
                               (get-input-set wiring-groups))
        possibilities (gen-possibilities (count variable-set))
        results-list
          (do-all-possibilities wiring-map variable-set possibilities)
        variables-list (take-results-from variable-set results-list)
        outputs-list (take-results-from output-set results-list)]
    (print-titles (count (first variables-list)))
    (println)
    (print-headers variables-list)
    (print-headers outputs-list)
    (println)
    (doall (map (fn [variables outputs]
                  (print-vals variables)
                  (print-vals outputs)
                  (println))
             variables-list
             outputs-list))))
```

Example input file:

```
(a, 2) 
(b, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, OUT)
(c, OUT)
```

It's output:

```
INPUTS                        OUTPUTS
a         b         c         OUT       
true      true      true      false     
false     true      true      true      
true      false     true      true      
false     false     true      true      
true      true      false     true      
false     true      false     true      
true      false     false     true      
false     false     false     true
```

Answer (score 1):

The program generates the truth table for a logic circuit composed of NAND gates. The circuit is - or ought to be - a [directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). Several of your functions apply to directed graphs in general.

Your main concerns are

1. how you represent the graph internally
2. how you represent the truth table
3. how you derive the truth table from the graph.

So far, I've dealt with (1) and a little bit of (2).

Most of the revisions I suggest involve using functions from the [sequence library](https://clojure.org/reference/sequences#_the_seq_library) instead of loops or even `reduce`s. These changes, even if some make the program slower, do - I hope - make it clearer.

---

You're given a list of [edges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_(graph_theory)). Since you're working out the output for a given set of inputs, you need to know, for each [vertex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_(graph_theory)), what its predecessors are. One function to do it is ...

```
(defn get-wiring-map [arc-list]
  (reduce
    (fn [ans [p s]]
      (assoc ans s (conj (get ans s []) p)))
      {}
      arc-list))
```

For instance, given

```
(def arc-list '((a, 2) (b, 2) (2, 3) (3, OUT) (c, OUT)))
```

then

```
(get-wiring-map arc-list)
;{OUT [3 c], 3 [2], 2 [a b]}
```

(Your example with symbols and numbers instead of strings).

You made somewhat heavy weather of this. Your `get-wiring-map` uses - directly or indirectly - `merge-wires`, `get-wiring-map-no-defaults`, and `add-defaults`.

Your version inserts a default `true` value into single collection values;

```
(get-wiring-map arc-list)
;{2 (a b), 3 (2 true), OUT (3 c)}
```

You don't need this, if you organise the calculation better (yet to be shown).

Your `get-input-set` is clearer as

```
(defn get-input-set
  [wiring-groups]
  (->> wiring-groups (map first) (into #{})))
```

I like the way you have generated the lines for the truth table in your `gen-possibilities` function. I'd do it like this:

```
(defn double-list [l] (concat l l))
(defn double-elements [l] (interleave l l))

(defn gen-possibilities [letter-count]
  (let [double (fn [all] (conj (map double-elements all) (double-list (first all))))
        start (list (list true false))]
    (nth (iterate double start) (dec letter-count))))
```

For example,

```
(gen-possibilities 3)
;((true false true false true false true false)
; (true true false false true true false false)
; (true true true true false false false false))
```

*Notes*

- I like your pretty-printing, but keep it separate. Once you touch the
  edges of the system with input or output, your program becomes harder
  to test.